# Split string into Multiple Rows and Columns using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I working on one SP which will split data present in one of the input parameter to multiple rows and column and will insert the same into table.

Format of the that string will be `<ID>-<Name>|<ID1>-<Name1>|<ID2>-<Name2>`  e.g. `145-Test.txt|236-Test1.png`

Expected output of the the provided example will be as below

```
ID  |  Name
145    Test.txt
236    Test1.png
```

Using below query I am able to split data into rows on the basis of `|` separator

```
select   REGEXP_SUBSTR('145-Test.txt|236-Test1.png','[^|]+', 1, level) from DUAL
connect by regexp_substr('145-Test.txt|236-Test1.png', '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

also using below query I am able to split string data into columns on the basis of `-` separator

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('145-Test.txt', '[^-]+', 1, 1) ID,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR('145-Test.txt', '[^-]+', 1, 2) Name
FROM DUAL;
```

Need help to merge these two queries so that I can get the expected output from single query only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple string functions:

```sql
WITH files ( value, start_pos, hyphen_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         INSTR( value, '-', 1, 1 ),
         INSTR( value, '|', 1, 1 )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR( value, '-', end_pos + 1, 1 ),
         INSTR( value, '|', end_pos + 1, 1 )
  FROM   files
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( value, start_pos, hyphen_pos - start_pos ) ) AS id,
       CASE end_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( value, hyphen_pos + 1 )
       ELSE SUBSTR( value, hyphen_pos + 1, end_pos - hyphen_pos - 1 )
       END AS filename
FROM   files
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '145-Test.txt|236-Test1.png' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '999-Test2_1.id|998-Test2_2.id' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '555-Test3_1.id' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>   ID | FILENAME  
> ---: | :---------
>  145 | Test.txt  
>  999 | Test2_1.id
>  555 | Test3_1.id
> null | null      
>  236 | Test1.png 
>  998 | Test2_2.id
> ```

---

Or, if you want to use regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       filename
FROM   table_name
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '(\d+)-(.*?)(\||$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) )
                  AS id,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '(\d+)-(.*?)(\||$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 2 )
                  AS filename
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( value, '(\d+)-(.*?)(\||$)' )
       );
```

or you can adapt your query:

```sql
SELECT id,
       filename
FROM   table_name
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( value,'[^|-]+', 1, 2 * level - 1 ) AS id,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR( value,'[^|-]+', 1, 2 * level - 0 ) AS filename
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY 2 * LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( value, '[^|-]+' )
       );
```

Which both output the same as the simple string functions.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8bd9fef92540db0ecbd6e2e8b9e36f3d)*